# Criar sub-listas em python

Tags: python, lista

Criei o seguinte código:

```
    self.buckets = [[], []]

    for i in self.keys:
        for ii in self.lista:
            if i % len(lista) == ii:
                self.buckets[ii].append(i)
```

Que adiciona os elementos de uma lista no caso "self.keys", em outra lista "self.buckets", de acordo com o resto da divisão pelo "len(lista)". Ou seja, digamos que o elemento da vez seja "self.keys = 10" e o "lista = 0", como o resto da divisão seria 0 esse elemento deve ser adicionado no slot 0 da lista "self.buckets".

A questão é que o código acima funciona, mas não é tão prático, já que preciso criar manualmente todas as sub-listas, ex:

```
self.buckets = [[], []]
```

Devido a isso, queria se tem como automatizar essa criação de sub-listas, ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa criar uma lista com `n` sublistas, todas vazias.
Você pode fazer usando [compreensão de listas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista):

```
numeroDeSublistas = 4
self.buckets = [[] for _ in range(numeroDeSublistas)]
```

O que retorna:

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

Como desejado.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, vlw mesmo !